# + Operator c# with string

Tags: c#, math, operator-keyword

I have got this code down below which should multiply two variables and add to it amount from textbox `kpriplac`. but when the multiplied value is 10 and kpriplac value is for example also 10 the output is 1010. But I need that output to be 20. I have also checked [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Where do I make a mistake? Thanks for your time reading this.

```
if (double.TryParse(comboBoxText, out comboxValue) && int.TryParse(textBox16.Text.Trim(), out textboxValue))
{
    textBox19.Text = ((comboxValue * textboxValue) + (kpriplac.Text)).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Where is `kpriplac.Text` converted to an `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` operator with strings operate as concatenate operator. You need to parse string to int or float.

for example:

```
textBox19.Text = ((comboxValue * textboxValue) + Convert.ToInt32(kpriplac.Text)).ToString();
```

#### Edit

Pleas make sure `kpriplac.Text` is:

- Is not empty
- Not contains only spaces
- Not contains the character or non convertible string.

If it then handle accordingly.

[Convert Class Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.convert.aspx)

Comment: -1 because this code will throw an exception if kpriplac.Text is empty. Like Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: Not obvious for as naiive as the asker. Who doesn't even knows how concatenation of string and int work?

Comment: because i still don't like the way code is written It isn't the right way to do it. :)

Answer (score 2):

As it stands, your code is adding a number to a string which is implicitly calling `ToString()` on the `(comboxValue * textboxValue)` expression and *performing string concatenation*.

You need to parse the value in `kpriplac.Text` into a numeric type as well, in much the same manner you are doing for `comboBoxText` and `textBox16.Text`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call int.Parse on every string, and then multiply or add the parsed values together, finally converting them back to string.

Use int.Parse only if you're **sure** that the given string is indeed an integer. If it isn't, exceptions are thrown. If you're unsure and want to handle them manually, use int.TryParse instead.

Answer (score 1):

You face this because

```
 (comboxValue * textboxValue)
```

is an **integer**,whereas

```
 kpriplac.Text
```

is a **string**

**In C# string + int = string.**
So lets say multiplication returns you 10. And you have got 10 in your text box as well

so what will happen is

```
        10 + "10"  = 1010
```

Change your code to

```
 if (double.TryParse(comboBoxText, out comboxValue) && int.TryParse(textBox16.Text.Trim(), out textboxValue))
 {
    int tempValue = 0;
    if(int.TryParse(kpriplac.Text,out tempValue))
         textBox19.Text = ((comboxValue * textboxValue) + tempValue).ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> Convert.ToInt32(((comboxValue * textboxValue) + (kpriplac.Text))).ToString();

Comment: -1 because it will not return the desired result. It will still return 1010.